# Constant as polygon fill in plotly

Tags: r, plotly, geospatial, geo

Is there a simple way to fill polygons with a single color in plotly? The color argument works below but not fill. Or should I trick choropleth with a constant instead of a variable?

```
library(sf)
library(plotly)
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
plot_geo(nc, color = I("red"), fill=I("blue"))
```

Comment: I think the `color` argument _is_ the fill colour. `plot_geo(nc, color = I("red"))` fills in red (though a lighter shade - you might need `alpha = 1`). `stroke` seems to change the border colour: `plot_geo(nc, color = I("blue"), stroke = I("red"), alpha = 1)`

Comment: Thank you, yes! This is reversed from ggplot so it threw me!